# Error deploying ZooKeeper on Fabric8

Tags: apache-zookeeper, openshift-origin, fabric8

I am trying to run the pre-packaged ZooKeeper within Fabric8.  Three instances are created and linked as an ensemble.  However, when I open one of the logs from the Pods UI, I see errors like below.  Does anyone know how to fix?

```
16:59:39,387 [myid:2] - WARN [QuorumPeer[myid=2]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:QuorumCnxManager@400] - Cannot open channel to 1 at election address zookeeper-1:3888
java.net.UnknownHostException: zookeeper-1
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:381)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectAll(QuorumCnxManager.java:426)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection.lookForLeader(FastLeaderElection.java:843)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:822)
2016-05-17 16:59:39,395 [myid:2] - WARN [QuorumPeer[myid=2]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:QuorumPeer$QuorumServer@155] - Failed to resolve address: zookeeper-1
java.net.UnknownHostException: zookeeper-1: unknown error
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:907)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1302)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1255)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1171)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1105)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1055)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer$QuorumServer.recreateSocketAddresses(QuorumPeer.java:148)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:407)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectAll(QuorumCnxManager.java:426)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection.lookForLeader(FastLeaderElection.java:843)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:822)
2016-05-17 16:59:39,395 [myid:2] - WARN [QuorumPeer[myid=2]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:QuorumCnxManager@400] - Cannot open channel to 3 at election address zookeeper-3:3888
java.net.UnknownHostException: zookeeper-3
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:381)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectAll(QuorumCnxManager.java:426)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection.lookForLeader(FastLeaderElection.java:843)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:822)
2016-05-17 16:59:39,402 [myid:2] - WARN [QuorumPeer[myid=2]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:QuorumPeer$QuorumServer@155] - Failed to resolve address: zookeeper-3
java.net.UnknownHostException: zookeeper-3: unknown error
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:907)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1302)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1255)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1171)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1105)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1055)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer$QuorumServer.recreateSocketAddresses(QuorumPeer.java:148)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:407)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectAll(QuorumCnxManager.java:426)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection.lookForLeader(FastLeaderElection.java:843)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:822)
2016-05-17 16:59:39,402 [myid:2] - INFO [QuorumPeer[myid=2]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:FastLeaderElection@852] - Notification time out: 60000
2016-05-17 17:00:39,402 [myid:2] - WARN         [QuorumPeer[myid=2]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:QuorumCnxManager@400] - Cannot open channel to 1 at election address zookeeper-1:3888
```

Comment: Can you also post your zoo.cfg file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Failed to resolve address: zookeeper-3
...
Failed to resolve address: zookeeper-1
```

Zookeeper initially starts out and tries to do a leader election after trying to connect to all reachable instances. It seems none of your instances are reachable.

You probably forgot to update the entries in `zoo.cfg` file. Here is what a default zoo.cfg looks like

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
server.2=zoo2:2888:3888
server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
```

You need to update zoo1, zoo2, zoo3 with appropriate hostnames or ips which resolve to unique hostnames

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure all of your nodes know the others by hostname (not by IP)
  by updating your local DNS or `hosts` file on every node

**OR**

- Change your ZooKeeper configuration (`zoo.cfg`) to use IP adresses instead of
  nodes hostname.

ZooKeeper try to resolve the hostname but cannot, hence the error.